# Google Scripts get active sheet is always returning left most sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a couple functions that are trigger buttons in a google sheet to switch tabs and set the active sheet. What is happening is the active sheet is always the left most tab. Ideally I would like to hide all the tabs that the buttons trigger so there isn't much clutter to the spreadsheet, but since the active sheet is always, in this case Dashboard, the current tab I'm on gets closed and it boots me to Round Scorecard. Very new to programming so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  hideUnnecessarySheets();
  
}

function hideUnnecessarySheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];

    // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Dashboard") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Score Card")||
       (sheet.getName() == "Round Scoreboard")
      ) continue;

      if (
      sheet.getName() == SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()
      ) continue;
      hideSheet(sheet.getName());
  } 

} 

function hideSheet(sheetName) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).hideSheet();
   
}

 

function goToSheet(sheetName, row, col) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you wanted to use break; instead of continue; the loop will continue to the last sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  const nS = ["Dashboard","Score Card","Round Scoreboard"];
  e.source.getSheets().filter(sh => !~nS.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => sh.hideSheet());
}
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly! The only issue is when I click one of my buttons to take me to a hidden sheet it loads then kicks me back to one of the sheets we have listed to not hide.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do on every selection change

Comment: Right, but if I want to view one of the tabs that is hidden is there a way I can keep that active until I return to one of the 3 sheets that is specified?

Comment: You could add another function that adds another sheet to the list by storing the list in PropertiesService.

Comment: But then you'll probably want yet another button to remove pages from the list.  As you increase your requirements you continue to require modifications to you projects script.  Which is exactly why you need to learn how to do this stuff on your own.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into doing that. Thanks for your help!